# Lists inside dictionary. How to iterate to get a specific value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to extract a value from a list in a dictionary. Here's a snippet
of the list inside the dict:

```
u'anomalies_bar_chart': {u'sleepy_client': 0, u'high_wifi_retries': 0, u'high_wifi_latency': 0, u'sta_dns_timeout': 0, u'weak_signal': 0, u'sta_arp_timeout': 0, u'sta_ip_timeout': 0, u'high_tcp_packet_loss': 0, u'poor_stream_eff': 0, u'low_phy_rate': 0, u'high_tcp_latency': 0}, u'tx_tcp_stats': {u'stalls': 0, u'lat_max':
```

This is what I got so far, but I'm getting a Key Error

```
for ap in c.get_aps():
    for sub in ap['anomalies_bar_chart']
        print sub['sleepy_client']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're in Python2, so `'anomalies_bar_chart' != u'anomalies_bar_chart'`

Comment: Is there a key called, _literally_, `'anomalies_bar_chart'`? Spoiler: no, there is _not_.

Comment: Also, you don't have a list inside a dictionary. You have a dictionary inside a dictionary.

Comment: you want the value associated with the dictionary key, right? assuming your dictionary ("mydict") is setup correctly, this should work: `for key in mydict.viewkeys():
 print mydict.get(key)`

Comment: I ran type() on it and it returns as a list. But then again when I try to:                            `my_list = c.get_aps() 
print my_list[0]['anomalies_bar_chart']`
It prints a key error again.
`print my_list[0]`
returns the whole thing
`print my_list[0][1]`
Key error again o.O

What am I missing here?

Comment: @r1kchartrand The data you display above _is_ a dictionary. You've shown us `my_list[0]`, it looks like. That's fine, but unclear per the question. Also: did you read my comment? It explains the `KeyError`.

Comment: @r1kchartrand what is the source code that created "'anomalies_bar_chart'" (in your question you just show output of `print anomalies_bar_chart`)